# Select products from tag group or other which are not in group

Tags: mysql

How select **products** which has *tag red* in *tag_group color* or product which does NOT have *tag_group color*? Expected result is on bottom.

---

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2caf6a/1

---

```
SELECT product.name
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_tag ON product.id = product_tag.product_id
INNER JOIN tag ON product_tag.tag_id = tag.id
INNER JOIN tag_group ON tag.tag_group_id = tag_group.id
WHERE (tag_group.name = 'color' AND tag.name = 'red') OR ...
```

What I tried

```
... tag_group.name != 'color'
```

or this

```
... product_tag.tag_id NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

but its return **ruby, crystal, emerald** because

---

**Schema**

[image]

---

**Data**

Product

```
+---------------+
| id | name     |
+---------------+
| 1  | ruby     |
| 2  | emerald  |
| 3  | sapphire |
| 3  | crystal  |
+---------------+
```

product_tag

```
+------------+--------+
| product_id | tag_id |
+------------+--------+
|          1 |      1 |
|          2 |      2 |
|          3 |      3 |
|          4 |      4 |
|          2 |      4 |
+------------+--------+
```

tag

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | name  | tag_group_id |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  1 | red   |            1 |
|  2 | green |            1 |
|  3 | blue  |            1 |
|  4 | new   |            2 |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

tag_group

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | color  |
|  2 | ribbon |
+----+--------+
```

---

**expected result:**

```
+---------+
|  name   |
+---------+
| ruby    |
| crystal |
+---------+
```

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: i want result 2 rows => ruby, crystal (get 2 products) ... its for product filter // I will apply query to doctrine where i have more complex DQL ... i simplyfy what I want to simple example

Comment: Can you edit the question to show that?

Comment: @Strawberry added expected result